# Read the docs search broken

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am trying to write up a documentation using Sphinx in combination with the read the docs theme, but the search function seems to be broken.

I am running Python 3.7 with the latest version of Sphinx and the Read the Docs Theme (both installed with `pip install`) on Windows 10. After building the page and opening the index.html in the browser (tried Edge and Chrome) I am not able to search my offline documentation. The search page opens up but is only displaying the animation `Search -> Search . -> Search .. -> Search …`, If I change the theme back to a standard theme the search works without any problems.

As the search works for standard themes it does not seem to be a Browser related problem nor does it seem to be related to the fact that I am not hosting the page on localhost.

If I look at the errors in the console I see two errors

```
jquery.js:4 Failed to load file:///C:/user/documentation/_build/html/searchindex.js: 
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol 
schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

and

```
searchtools.js:144 Uncaught ReferenceError: Stemmer is not defined
at Object.query (searchtools.js:144)
at Object.setIndex (searchtools.js:83)
at searchindex.js:1
```

I could not find anything useful to solve this problem while searching online. Also refreshing the browser cache (`Ctrl + F5`) like described in https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/4026 did not work.

Did anyone experience the same issue?

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5460

Comment: @mzjn: Thank you for your comment. I already tried to install an older version of sphinx 1.7.9 but this did also not solve the problem.

Comment: If I download a ReadTheDocs documentation as HTML, the fact that the Search doesn't work is expected, right?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by using the following solution (https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx_rtd_theme/pull/672/commits/4b9053cb9e805211f227399d66d82361b3e2bf56).

**Credit goes to GitHub user @tk0miya.**

First, navigate to the Python installation folder and locate the `layout.html` inside `./Lib/site-packages/sphinx_rtd_theme/layout.html`.

Then replace line 191 - 204 containing

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        var DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS = { 
            URL_ROOT:'{{ url_root }}', 
            VERSION:'{{ release|e }}', 
            LANGUAGE:'{{ language }}', 
            COLLAPSE_INDEX:false, 
            FILE_SUFFIX:'{{ '' if no_search_suffix else file_suffix }}', 
            HAS_SOURCE:  {{ has_source|lower }}, 
            SOURCELINK_SUFFIX: '{{ sourcelink_suffix }}' 
        }; 
    </script> 
    {%- for scriptfile in script_files %} 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ pathto(scriptfile, 1) }}"></script> 
    {%- endfor %}
```

by the following code

```
{% if sphinx_version >= "1.8.0" %} 
      <script type="text/javascript" id="documentation_options" data-url_root="{{ pathto('', 1) }}" src="{{ pathto('_static/documentation_options.js', 1) }}"></script> 
      {%- for scriptfile in script_files %} 
        {{ js_tag(scriptfile) }} 
      {%- endfor %} 
    {% else %} 
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
          var DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS = { 
              URL_ROOT:'{{ url_root }}', 
              VERSION:'{{ release|e }}', 
              LANGUAGE:'{{ language }}', 
              COLLAPSE_INDEX:false, 
              FILE_SUFFIX:'{{ '' if no_search_suffix else file_suffix }}', 
              HAS_SOURCE:  {{ has_source|lower }}, 
              SOURCELINK_SUFFIX: '{{ sourcelink_suffix }}' 
          }; 
      </script> 
      {%- for scriptfile in script_files %} 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ pathto(scriptfile, 1) }}"></script> 
      {%- endfor %} 
    {% endif %}
```

Then run `make clean` and `make html` inside your documentation folder for the console. It is important that the console commands are executed inside your documentation folder.

Comment: I'm seeing the same symptom in `sphinx 6.2.1`, but the structure of `layout.html` has changed a bit over the past five years. I wonder how to find the current version of this fix?